# Sort files and folders in the same way in Windows Explorer - sorted by names

Tags: windows, sorting, explorer

I just want to **see files and folders** (sorted/grouped by their name) in a list that does **NOT separate files and folders**.

I also don't want to order by `date modified` like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/204016/windows-explorer-sorts-files-and-folders-separately).

I already tried several solutions. But unfortunaletly non worked. And I don't want to use grouped by that splits it up into A-G... and so on.

Comment: Consider posting this question on SuperUser.com instead.

Comment: Ahh damnit, I just wanted to post it there. Is there a way to simply switch it to there? Or just recreate it there?

Comment: I don't have the power to move questions to other sites yet, but another moderator might jump in and do it. If you can't wait then I would repost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xplorer²** was able to solve this issue. Anyway I'm still interested in doing this in the Windows explorer without any external tools.

Just wrote a [**German Tutorial about this and xplorer²**](http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/03/08/windows-explorer-sortierung-f%C3%BCr-ordner-und-dateien-mit-xplorer%C2%B2/). It should be easy to understand also for non-Germans. ;)